# webpack third party libraries

Tags: webpack, semantic-ui, vue.js

I'm new to webpack, now i have a problem with third party libraries.

I'm using vue-cli to setup webpack for vue component files.

Now i wan't to use semantic-ui in this project, when i include the css file with require in my entry point it works fine, but when i do this with the js file from semantic (not the min version) webpack says me in the semantic.js file are 15000 errors.

I don't know what the problem is, pleas help me to understand.

Thanks

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

// add semantic
require('./assets/lib/semantic/semantic.css')
require('./assets/styles/helper.css')
require('./assets/lib/semantic/semantic.js')

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
 el: 'body',
 components: { App }
})
```

UPDATE: The most errors about semicolons and spaces

[log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jztcb.png)

[log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMgXc.png)

Comment: Attach the log please (atleast several messages)

Comment: there is only 15000 errors and a note about the 100k limit of babel. i think you don't want see all errors ;-)

Comment: I don't say "all errors"

Comment: i have add screenshots

Comment: Looks like this is styling errors. Don't you have ESLint in preLoaders?

Comment: I have ESLint in preLoaders, now i have deactivated ESLint. But won't work. How can i add semantic-ui to a vuejs app packed with webpack?

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: when i add jquery like semantic.js than i have a white screen wihout a error.(semantic need jquery)

Comment: i have found the solution - i must add jquery to $ var - thanks for help